# What is the story in which an alien was found on a barren planet and the media named it "Cutie-Pie"?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, short-stories

An alien was found on a barren planet by a space expedition, they catch it and bring it to earth. The alien did not live on that planet, it was just passing through. The alien was named "Cutie-Pie" by the media because it was beautiful. Later, the alien falls sick because the scientists are unable to determine its natural diet. Then, it escapes, has some adventures, befriends a human baby and later leaves earth. But, there is a telepathic link between the baby and the alien; and it remains for ever.

It was a short story from a collection. Can anyone find out who wrote it? And which publication it appeared?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could it be [Cutie Pie](http://www.fortunecity.com/wembley/pride/795/kate/Cutie.Pie.htm) by Nicholas Fisk? I googled 'Cutie-pie alien' and [this](http://vectoreditors.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/cutie-pie/) came up.

Comment: Yes, it is. But, I was looking for the book name.

Comment: the blog post says 'Sweets for a Stranger', is this correct?

Comment: Thank you for finding it was Nicholas Fisk. According to ISFDB.org, "Cutie Pie" appeared in the collection "Sweets from a Stranger and Other SF Stories".